# Sync Google Docs Action Items with Google Tasks

Tags: google-workspace, synchronization, google-workspace-for-business, google-apps-sync

In Google Docs (as well as Sheets and Slides), one can assign an "action item" (e.g. some to-do) to another person by marking him/her in a comment ([link](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/65129)).

Also, there is the "Google Tasks" feature available in Google's Mail/Calendar service ([link](https://support.google.com/calendar/answer/106237?hl=en)).

I am hoping to sync the two such that any "action" I have been assigned to in a Google Doc also shows up in my Tasks List as an item.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Gmail's Keyboard shortcut Shift-T will add the email to your to-do list if you have the shortcuts enabled in options, but I don't think you can automatically sync.